# How do I suppress Excel message for any pivot table update?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a pivot table to summarize some information and have added some formulas adjacent to the pivot table to do calculations on the numbers included in it.  I have created a macro that re-enters the formulas whenever the user changes the size of the pivot table (in the PivotTableUpdate event) by showing or hiding various rows/columns of data.

My problem is that whenever columns of data are added to the pivot table, it asks me "Do you want to replace the contents of the destination cells?"  I always click yes, because although the cells will be overwritten when the pivot table expands, the formulas will be re-entered in their correct cell and everything is fixed and formatted properly by the macro.

Therefore, I would like to know where I should put `application.displayalerts = false` so that it is effective to suppress the message box whenever the user expands the pivot table.

Comment: I don't think you can suppress the alert in this way. It would be a different story if the PT update were invoked in code. As it is, by the time `PivotTableUpdate` is called, it's too late. A work-around you can try is modify the macro to put the formulae in a safe place many columns to the right, and hide the white space between the PT and the formulae.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to find a separate event to attach the code to, which would occur before the message is displayed.  However, I have tried using the `PivotTableBeforeAllocateChanges`, `PivotTableBeforeCommitChanges`, and `PivotTableBeforeDiscardChanges` events without any luck.  I take it there are no other events that might possibly occur before the message is displayed.  If that is the case, I suppose I will have to use your suggested workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Hi tlewis3348 i think this is what you are looking for

```
Sub UpdateIt() 
    Dim iP As Integer 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 
    For iP = 1 To ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Count 
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables(iP).RefreshTable 
    Next 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you provide more information?  Where does this go, and what does it do?  I am trying to catch the event before the PivotTable is changed when the user adds a column.  It appears that this is just a macro to refresh the PivotTables in the workbook (while suppressing the error I'm trying to suppress).  I'm not sure how that helps since the user would still be adding columns to the PivotTable and the message would not be suppressed.  Therefore, if you could clarify what this is doing and how it accomplished what I want it to do, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW This solution worked great for me.  I just activated each sheet individually and called the UpdateIt function before doing anything else, e.g.,

```
Worksheets("RFS Monthly Summary").Activate
UpdateIt
Worksheets("RFS Daily Activity").Activate
UpdateIt
```