# How to suppress "overwrite existing data" alert within a pivottable update event?

Tags: excel, events, pivot-table, alerts, vba

**Situation:**

I am using a `PivotTableUpdate` event to clear a range to the right of a `PivotTable` and then insert values, in the next available column, to the right of the `PivotTable.DataBodyRange`.

**Single slicer item selection:**

In the first image below, I am selecting one slicer item and then using

```
.Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count, 25)
```

to clear a region to the right of the `DataBodyRange`. The `Resize` is to account for prior selections which may have populated a different column from the currently next available.

I am then using

```
.Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1) = "1"
```

to set the next available free column's value to, in this case, `1`.

**Example: One slicer item selection, table and pivot  in Sheet1:**

[image]

So I am going from "before" to "after" as shown below:

[image: Before and after]

This works fine. There is no change in the next available column address.

**Multi-item slicer selection:**

When I attempt the same thing with a multi-select the code halts with the standard "Alert before overwriting cells" i.e. I get:

> There is already data in..Do you want to replace it?

**Example: Multi slicer item selection, table and pivot in Sheet1:**

[image]

What I have tried:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

And

```
Application.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False
```

And (to clear the pop-up)

```
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

The message still appears for multi-select and doesn't go away until I manually press the <kbd>OK</kbd>

**Thoughts:**

I had thought perhaps the message is triggered before the event code is run, but I don't get this message when I overwrite the same range (i.e. single slicer item selection)

I know you can manually switch this alert off via the File > Options > Advanced Settings but am unsure how to suppress, via code, in my current code.

**Anyone have a solution on how to suppress this alert?**

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Target.DataBodyRange

        Dim clearRange As Range

        Set clearRange = .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count, 25)

        clearRange.ClearContents

        .Offset(, .Columns.Count).Resize(.Rows.Count, 1) = "1"

    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Test data:

```
| Trust | STP  | Val |
|-------|------|-----|
| A     | STPa | 1   |
| B     | STPb | 2   |
| C     | STPc | 3   |
```

References:

1. [Suppress Overwrite Existing Data Alert In VBA Macro](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/84268-suppress-overwrite-existing-data-alert-in-vba-macro)
2. [Prevent Overwrite Warning in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739577/prevent-overwrite-warning-in-vba)

Comment: It seems that you will need some workaround/change of approach. When PivotTableUpdate event is executed it is already too late. You may try other events https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-events/ however it probably would not help (see comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834775/how-do-i-suppress-excel-message-for-any-pivot-table-update). My tests indicate that none of the events happen before update by slicer. Btw. very nice question and post :)

Comment: @tomjohnriddle  thanks. I will have a look. The other thought I had earlier is that I simply place the insert  data much further away so no risk of overlap but will require me to group some columns to keep it all in screen view.

Comment: You may programatically hide some columns and make them visible if needed. Dirty solution but will work :)

Comment: Well my suspicion was the same as your comment about it already being too late inside the event so avoiding the possibility altogether seems to be the likely workaround. Not worried about coding the column hide think simple grouping will suffice. I will, in the real scenario, eventually put the slicer front end and backend the pivots.

Comment: So current hack is to try a public variable holding the pivottable.ColumnRange.Columns.Count where the pivotttable is a hidden one that has all the possible selection items in the columns. Then doing a plus 1 on this to set the start area for adding data i.e. no overlap can occur. This will be set in an Init procedure so is available before the event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted, by the time the event has fired it is too late.

My hack around was to create a public variable holding the pvt.ColumnRange.Columns.Count where the pvt is a hidden duplicate pivottable (of the one in question) that has all the possible selection items in the columns. Then doing a plus 1 on this to set the start area for adding data i.e. no overlap can occur. This was set in an Init procedure so is available before the event is triggered.